# Add Vintage Projector/jitter effect while recording a video

Tags: ios, iphone, video, camera

I want to develop a feature into an application, by which an vintage projector effect can be given to a recording video or a pre recorded video. If you want i an share an image. i want the effect similar to it, one part of the recording video is showing in the bottom frame and the bottom part of the recording video is showing in the top frame. Along with this the whole view should shake like a real vintage projector recording.![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)?

It has lots of options for video recording/processing and allows to add/combine different filters.

Comment: you'll probably need to create your own shader for it, simple enough to do though.